# User friendly SQLite database csv file import update solution

Tags: python, database, sqlite, csv

I was wondering if there is a way to allow a user to export a SQLite database as a .csv file, make some changes to it in a program like Excel, then upload that .csv file back to the table it came from using a record UPDATE method.

Currently I have a client that needed an inventory and pricing management system for their e-commerce store. I designed a database system and logic in Python 3 and SQLite. The system from a programming standpoint works flawlessly.

The problem I have is that there are some less then technical office staff that need to edit things like product markup within the database. Currently, I have them setup with SQLite DB Browser, from there they can edit products one at a time and write the changes to the database. They can also export tables to a .csv file for data manipulation in Excel.

The main issue is getting that .csv file back into the table it was exported from using an UPDATE method. When importing a .csv file to a table in SQLite DB Browser there is no way to perform an update import. It can only insert new rows by default and do to my table constraints that is a problem.

I like SQLite DB Browser because it is clean and simple and does exactly what I need. However, as soon as you have to edit more then one thing at a time and filter information in more complicated ways it starts to lack the functionality needed.

Is there a solution out there for SQLite DB Browser to tackle this problem? Is there a better software option all together to interact with a SQLite database that would give me that last bit of functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after researching some off the shelf options I found that the Devart Excel Add Ins did exactly what I needed. They are paid add ins, however, they seem to support almost all modern databases including SQlite. Once the add in is installed you can connect to a database and manipulate the data returned just like normal in Excel including bulk edits and advanced filtering, all changes are highlighted and can easily be written to the database with one click.

Overall I thought it was a pretty solid solution and everyone seems to be very happy with it as it made interacting with a database intuitive and non threatening to the more technically challenged.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [SQLiteForExcel](https://github.com/govert/SQLiteForExcel)? however, some coding is required.

Comment: No I havn't... how does that exactly work? It allows you to update a SQLite database via Excel macros?

Comment: I don't know, since I don't use MsOffice, buy here's an [example](http://www.gatekeeperforexcel.com/other-freebies.html) of using it to update SQLite.